# Order of elements of latex bibliography (date, pp.) in the References section

Tags: bibtex

I noticed that in my References section, in some references the "pp." appears before the date and for others, it is the opposite. I need to have this consistent through the References section such that for all the references in the section the date is written before the "pp."
[image]

There is a sample of .tex file:

```
\documentclass[ letterpaper, 10 pt, conference,numbers,square, sort&compress]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newif\iffoo %Declaration
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\newcommand{\raj}[1]{
    \textcolor{blue}{RJ:#1}

}





\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only needed if 
% you want to use the \thanks command

\overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed to meet printer requirements.

\title{\LARGE \bf
    TITLE}


\author{{ LIST OF AUTHORS
}}


\begin{document}


\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
% make the title area
%\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    ABSTRACT

\end{abstract}

%\iffalse
\begin{keywords}
    %% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
    kEYWORKS
\end{keywords}
%\fi




\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\section{Introduction}
Sample text, \cite{pif1}, \cite{a1_a}.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}


\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}

%%
%% End of file `elsarticle-template-num.tex'.
```

And here is the relevent part of the .bib file:

```
@ARTICLE{pif1, 
    author={S. {Ahmed} and Y. {Lee} and S. {Hyun} and I. {Koo}}, 
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Information Forensics and Security}, 
    title={Unsupervised Machine Learning-Based Detection of Covert Data Integrity Assault in Smart Grid Networks Utilizing Isolation Forest}, 
    year={2019}, 
    volume={14}, 
    number={10}, 
    pages={2765-2777}, 
    keywords={Power measurement;Smart grids;Data integrity;Feature extraction;State estimation;Communication networks;Cyber-security;cyber-assaults;machine learning;principal component analysis;state estimation;smart grids;isolation forest}, 
    doi={10.1109/TIFS.2019.2902822}, 
    ISSN={1556-6013}, 
    month={Oct},}

@INPROCEEDINGS{a1_a, 
    author={A. P. {Mathur} and N. O. {Tippenhauer}}, 
    booktitle={2016 International Workshop on Cyber-physical Systems for Smart Water Networks (CySWater)}, 
    title={{S}{W}a{T}: a water treatment testbed for research and training on ICS security}, 
    year={2016}, 
    volume={}, 
    number={}, 
    pages={31-36}, 
    keywords={industrial control;security of data;training;water treatment;SWaT;water treatment testbed;training;ICS security;industrial control system;security research;attack detection algorithms;system identification;Sensors;Actuators;Feeds;Process control;Chemicals;Chemical sensors;Security;Cyber Physical Systems;Industrial Control Systems;Cyber Attacks;Cyber Defense;Water Testbed}, 
    doi={10.1109/CySWater.2016.7469060}, 
    ISSN={}, 
    month={April},}
```

Comment: Please add your minimal document (MWE) code as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is added now.